# query for making matrix style .rdl report using report wizard

Tags: sql, reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008

I need help writing the query for a matrix style report.

My data is in the following format

```
id    body_part   incident_type1  incident_type2   incident_type3 
1     head        PPE             null             null 
2     ankle       Unsafe Act      Facility         null
3     hand        null            null             null
4     head        Facility        PPE              Unsafe Act
```

I want the rows to be the body parts and columns to be incident types.  If incident_type1 is null, then I want a count in a "n/a" column.  But, if incident_type2 and/or 3 is null, I do not want those to count in the "n/a" column.

```
            Facility    Unsafe Act    PPE     N/A
ankle        1            1            0       0
hand         0            0            0       1
head         1            1            2       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a stored procedure where I inserted the data into a temp table.  I was then able to use the report wizard with "EXEC SP_Name" as the query.  Then I selected Body_part as my rows, Incident_type as my columns, and Totals as my data.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Body_part VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Incident_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT ISNULL(Body_part, 'N/A'), ISNULL(Incident_type, 'N/A')
FROM [safety].vwIncomingPINS
WHERE submitted_on >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND submitted_on <=getdate()

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT ISNULL(Body_part, 'N/A'), Incident_type2
FROM [safety].vwIncomingPINS
WHERE submitted_on >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND submitted_on <=getdate() AND Incident_type2 IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT ISNULL(Body_part, 'N/A'), Incident_type3
FROM [safety].vwIncomingPINS
WHERE submitted_on >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND submitted_on <=getdate() AND Incident_type3 IS NOT NULL

SELECT Body_part, Incident_type, count(*) AS Totals from #tmp
GROUP BY Body_part, Incident_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this:

```
select body_part
  , Facility = sum(case when incident_type1 = 'Facility' or incident_type2 = 'Facility'  or incident_type3 = 'Facility' then 1 else 0 end)
  , [Unsafe Act] = sum(case when incident_type1 = 'Unsafe Act' or incident_type2 = 'Unsafe Act'  or incident_type3 = 'Unsafe Act' then 1 else 0 end)
  , PPE = sum(case when incident_type1 = 'PPE' or incident_type2 = 'PPE'  or incident_type3 = 'PPE' then 1 else 0 end)
  , [N/A] = sum(case when incident_type1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
from Incidents
group by body_part
order by body_part
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb4f3b/1).

This assumes known incident types and that the same row will not have the same incident type multiple times.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically populate the columns and rows b/c I do not know all of the values that will be there.